Role Assignment using ARM template on different Resource Group
I have the below ARM template that will run on ResourceGroupA and do a role assignment on a resource present in ResourceGroupB. The resources that I am using is Managed Identity in RG-A and KeyVault in RG-B. Whenever I run, I am having issues resolving the key vault resource that is used.
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "managedIdentityName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "mymanagedidentityname"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "kvResourceGroupName": "ResourceGroupB",
    "kvName": "myKv",
    "userAssignedIdentityApiVersion": "2018-11-30",
    "kvSecretsUserRoleId": "b86a8fe4-44ce-4948-aee5-eccb2c155cd7"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
      "name": "[guid(concat(subscription().id, variables('kvName'), parameters('managedIdentityName'), variables('kvSecretsUserRoleId')))]",
      "scope": "[format('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{2}', subscription().subscriptionId, variables('kvResourceGroupName'), variables('kvName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', variables('kvSecretsUserRoleId'))]",
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/', parameters('managedIdentityName')), '2018-11-30').principalId]"
      }
    }
  ]
}

The error that I get says "The Resource 'myKv' under resource group 'ResourceGroupA' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix."

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

the role assignment will be perform on the resource in ResourceGroupB so you need to do the other way around. create a deployment for ResourceGroupB and get a reference to the managed identity in resourcegroupA

So this is part of a larger template where more resources are created. I need to setup infra and assign roles and deploy my app after. With your suggestion this will be multiple pipelines. I see this as a very common scenario

you can use inner deployment for that. also you should use bicep that woul make your life easier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep


Role Assignment using ARM template on different Resource Group

I do agree with Thomos for suggesting same point.
If you are assigning the role in a different resource group and the identity is in another resource group, make sure to specify the identity's resource group details in the ARM template and deploy it in the Key Vault's resource group
Here is the updated ARM code for role assignment.
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "managedIdentityName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Venkat-UAM"
    },
    "managedIdentityResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Venkat-RG"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "kvResourceGroupName": "Key_vault",
    "kvName": "Venkt-Vault",
    "userAssignedIdentityApiVersion": "2018-11-30",
    "kvSecretsUserRoleId": "4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
      "name": "[guid(concat(subscription().id, variables('kvName'), parameters('managedIdentityName'), variables('kvSecretsUserRoleId')))]",
      "scope": "[format('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/{2}', subscription().subscriptionId, variables('kvResourceGroupName'), variables('kvName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', variables('kvSecretsUserRoleId'))]",
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('managedIdentityResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('managedIdentityName')), variables('userAssignedIdentityApiVersion')).principalId]"
      }
    }
  ]
}

In my case UAM(Identity)in [Venkat-RG] and Key vault in [Key_vault] resource group.
While deploying the script, make sure to deploy it in Resource Group B
 New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "Key_vault" -TemplateFile "roleassignment.json"

Output:

After executing the script, the role has been successfully assigned to the Key Vault.


Thanks Venkat, I will try this but my issue is that I have a larger template that sets up entire infra in one RG where the Key Vault is the only resource thats shared. Probably this will be the case for UAMidentity as well. Thomas suggested to use inner deployment so probably I can set your template inside mine to see if that works?

Sure, please check and confirm @narcs.

I am aware of this, I was just waiting for more options on how to do it in a single arm template using inner deployment.
